# Space Bar (32) was not working at keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to enter only string valriable into the textbox but space bar was not working please some one help me friends. . .

```
$(".onlyname").keypress(function (evt) {
  evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
  var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
    ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
  if (charCode > 31 && (charCode == 9 || charCode == 40 || charCode == 39 || charCode == 32 || charCode == 37 || charCode == 27 || charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
    (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
    $('#error').attr('class', 'errorMessage');
    $('#error').text("Enter Only Alphabets Value");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    $('#error').attr('class', ' display: none;');
    $('#error').text("");
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `keydown` event -- "The keypress event is similar to the keydown event, except that modifier and non-printing keys such as Shift, Esc, and delete trigger keydown events but not keypress events." -- http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: `$('#error').attr('class', ' display: none;');` is not right it should be `$('#error').css('display','none');`

Comment: Also in jQuery `e.which` is normalized, you don't need all that `charCode` code. Same with `evt`.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qesowipu/1/edit see this fiddle and help me if i put keydown event then it take a input afterwards showing error

Comment: its working only , may be other condition '&&' is not satisfied so its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition is wrong

```
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode == 9 || charCode == 40 || charCode == 39 || charCode == 32 || charCode == 37 || charCode == 27 || charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
    (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
```

Space bar key code is 32, so when you type space this if condition is satisified and it prints the error.

Try tis fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nfDM8/

Or try this edit in your own code

```
     $(".onlyname").keypress(function (evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
        var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
          ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
        if (charCode > 32 && (charCode == 9 || charCode == 40 || charCode == 39 || charCode == 37 || charCode == 27 || charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
          (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
            alert("Enter Only Alphabets Value");
            return false;
        }
        else {            
            return true;       
        }
    });
```